# Piece-wise initialization of very large C struct

Tags: c, struct, constants, initializing

My embedded application stores (in ROM, const) very large, very nested struct.
I'm looking for a tidy way to initialize it.
So instead writing :

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t    n1;
    float       fArr[5];
    struct {
        char    cArr[1000];
        int32_t n3;
    }subStruct;
    // ... and on and on 
}Config_t;

const Config_t cfg = {
    .n1 = 5,
    .fArr = {1.0, 2.0, 0, -5.6, 8.8},
    .subStruct.cArr = {1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3/*etc*/},
    .subStruct.n3 = 3
};
```

Use something like :

```
const float fArrAux[5] = { 1.0, 2.0, 0, -5.6, 8.8 };
const char cArrAux[1000] = { 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3/*etc*/ };

const Config_t cfg = {
    .n1 = 5,
    .fArr = fArrAux,            // ?
    .subStruct.cArr = cArrAux,  // ?
    .subStruct.n3 = 3
};
```

Is there a recommended way to do it so that the main struct remain contiguous (excl. members padding) in memory (its in flash so I want to burn it in one pass).

Also, will the auxiliary definitions (fArrAux, cArrAux) in such setting will consume memory (hence double the footprint) ?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you feel the 2nd approach would be more tidied up then the 1st? Also this question seems to be two questions: 1.) on initialisations and 2.) on avoiding padding

Comment: "*will the auxiliary definitions (fArrAux, cArrAux) in such setting will consume memory*" probably yes.

Comment: The first variant is cleaner; it clearly initializes what you want to initialize and clearly doesn't run any risk of unexpected overhead.  The second doesn't work anyway — at least, not as written — which is another reason to prefer the first.

Comment: I will use a variation of the first one but your example must not reflect your real case; This question is primary opinion based;

Answer (score 2):

Notice that in C, executable code *always* appear inside functions.

Both kind of initializations (assuming it is of `static` or global data, *outside* of any function code) are happening at build time and are practically initializing some kind of [code segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment).

Your second variant makes sense (and should compile) only if `.fArr` and `.subStruct.cArr` are pointers (not arrays). So as given, it does not compile:

```
e.c:18:13: error: incompatible types when initializing type ‘float’ 
                  using type ‘const float *’
     .fArr = fArrAux,            // ?
             ^~~~~~~
```

You could consider changing your build procedure to e.g. generate some C definition, e.g. in some large generated `.c` file containing stuff similar to the first variant.

Answer (score 2):

If you just  want to visually separate long array initializers, you might consider to define them as macros:

```
#define CFG_FARR             { 1.0, 2.0, 0, -5.6, 8.8 }
#define CFG_SUBSTRUCT_CARR   { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, /*etc*/ }

const Config_t cfg = {
    .n1 = 5,
    .fArr = CFG_FARR,
    .subStruct.cArr = CFG_SUBSTRUCT_CARR,
    .subStruct.n3 = 3
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have the actual data in a file that you can generate or create with some external tool, which could also allow you to check the correctness of the data before assigning it as initializers to your structure(s) and array(s):

```
const Config_t cfg = {
    .n1 = 5,
    .fArr = 
#include "fArrData.txt"
    ,
    .subStruct.cArr = 
#include "cArrData.txt"
    ,
    .subStruct.n3 = 3
};
```

Disclaimer: I didn't test this. In other situations I wrote a little program to do this for me.